# How to store JSON in model - SpringBoot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

Have JSON that looks like this:

```
"quote": [
    {
      "market": "APX Power NL Hourly",
      "date_applied": 1573599600000,
      "content": [
        {
          "gameId": "Order"...
```

I should save it to next model class:

```
public class GameDataResponse {    
    @JsonProperty(value = "gameId")
    public final String gameId;

    public GameDataResponse(
            String gameId, {
            notNull(gameId, "gameId must be set");
            this.gameId = gameId;
        } 
    public static GameDataResponse gameDataResponse(String gameId) {
        return new GameDataResponse(gameId);
    }
}
```

In `gameDataResponse` function I have to save `gameId` value from node to variable `gameId` but I am not sure if I am doing it right.

```
private GameDataResponse gameDataResponse(JsonNode node) {            
    return GameDataResponse.gameDataResponse(asString(node.get("gameId")));
}
```

With above code my variable is still empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what the variable `node` contains. Please try to debug the line `asString(node.get("gameId"))` to see what the variable `node` contains. This will let you know if this variable contains the JsonNode that you expect.
Update after reading your comment: It looks like you need to navigate through the JsonNode to the corresponding field. The path should be as follows for the first gameId: "quote[0]/content[0]/gameId". There are multiple ways to get to this value.

Comment: I did and I do see key with name `gameId`but I am not getting it

Comment: In your debugger, what happens when you execute then `asString(node.get("gameId"))`? What does the variable `node` look like (JSON format)?

Comment: I updated my question, you will see how JSON looks

Comment: It looks like you need to navigate through the JsonNode to the corresponding field. The path should be as follows for the first gameId: "quote[0]/content[0]/gameId". There are multiple ways to get to this value. One way is to navigate node by node, e.g., `node.get("quote")` will give you the array of nodes. You can either pick the first element or iterate through them. Please visit the JsonNode documentation or tutorials on how to navigate through a JsonNode to find the value you need.

Comment: You were right, after debug I found out that problem was in another part of code. This one working just fine :) Can you edit your answer/explanation, so I can accept.

Comment: @user9347049 I updated the answer with the details from the comment ;)